# Codeingiter CSRF throwing error only one one computer

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a website that has been working fine for around 3 months now (with CSRF enabled), but I just got a netbook acer aspire 1, (browser is IE 9.0.8112), and all of a sudden I get a CSRF error when trying to submit a form! I am using codeigniter version 2 and I only have this problem on the one computer. (The action you have requested is not allowed).

What could possbily be going on here? When I use firefox on the same machine everything works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible cause for this behavior may be that cookies are disabled on that particular browser.  CSRF relies on cookies being enabled.